# Same question, different OS

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344711/python3-check-if-unicode-character-is-not-present) about accessing font information with python was closed as a duplicate of [this older question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458696/finding-out-what-characters-a-font-supports) Dealing with fonts is inherently system-dependent, and although the older question asks exactly the same thing, it is about Linux. The OP for the new question is on OS X (this was not in the original question text, but see comments), and reports that none of the answers to the older question apply.

What's the right thing to do in this situation? **My guess:** Edit the new question to specify OS, and request to reopen.

In fact I might have an answer to the new question, but it would be off-topic for the original since it's specific to OS X. So I don't see a good alternative to reopening, unless the older question is mangled to make it OS-independent (which would be unfair to the existing answers).

Comment: Yup, sounds like the right path.

Comment: This question on itself is valid – but you must find a better example! The OP of that question did not respond to my query *why* "it does not work", so I went and tested the proposed answer. It *does* work.